# Fixing (or adding features to) a Rails server in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I would like to know what the best practice is for taking a ruby on rails application in production and adding a feature to it or debugging a broken feature?

What I mean is, say you have a working application and you have lots of people using it. You want to add a new feature to this app. You clone your application to your local machine. Create a new feature (or w/e) branch.

Now what do you change/do so you don't destroy your database and so you are able to test and debug this application on your local machine?

*Also, let's say this is an older rails application with an older ruby version.*

I would also like to note that I am having trouble finding any information this and am willing to read books and lots of text to learn if it is a very involved task.

Answer (score 1):

Although the complexity of this type of operation varies quite a bit, usually based on the complexity of the application itself, I think a few generalizations can be made.

**Tests**

Obviously, do not break any existing tests. Write tests for you new functionality, even if they are the first tests in the application.

**Data**

Ideally, you will have data to work with that very closely mirrors your production data. In some cases (CMS) this may be an actual dump of the production database and assets, restored locally. In other cases (billing portal for a hospital), you will probably need to rely on well-constructed seed data. Once your automated tests pass, you can perform manual QA against the (possibly simulated) production data.

**Staging**

If you do not have a staging environment that 100% mirrors your production environment, set one up now. This should be set up as close as you possibly can to your production environment, using the database guidelines from above. Merge your feature branch into staging prior to merging it into production. This will allow you to do a final QA test in a near-production environment. This can be used to test not only new application features, but new server versions, ruby version, etc.

**CI/CD**

It is becoming very common to use CI/CD to automate the testing and deployment of feature branches. This can help enforce code quality guidelines. It can also allow you to run the tests in an environment that matches production, for extra peace of mind.

**Backups**

Obviously, even with all of this, things can still go wrong. Keeping up-to-date backups is vital, for worst case scenarios.

Comment: As this is an older Ruby/Rails version, you may consider adding [Brakeman](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman) to your CI/CD pipeline...